# Minimum of sum of reciprocals of positive real numbers with inequality costraint

Tags: summation, nonlinear-optimization, upper-lower-bounds, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

I am facing a problem where you have to find the minimum of the function
\begin{equation}
f(a_1,...,a_n) = \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{a_i}
\end{equation}
constrained to
\begin{equation}
\sum_{i=1}^n a_i = 2m
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}
a_1 \leq m \leq a_n
\end{equation}
where $a_1$ and $a_n$ are respectively the smallest and the largest element and $a_i>0\ \forall i$. Can we find the minimum of $f(a_1,...,a_n)$ without resorting to non-linear optimization methods?

**ADDITIONAL THOUGHTS:**

I already faced a [similar problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3917912/lower-bound-for-sum-of-reciprocals-of-positive-real-numbers) without the constraints on $a_1$ and $a_n$ that can be solved through Cauchy-Schwarz inequality. If we apply C-S trying to exclude one of the elements, say $a_j$, we find
\begin{equation}
      \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{a_i} \geq \frac{(n-1)^2}{2m- a_j} + \frac{1}{a_j}\ .
\end{equation}
which according to Monte Carlo simulations takes the minimum when $a_j=m$. In fact, the result should be
\begin{equation}
   f(a_1,...,a_n) \geq \frac{(n-1)^2}{m} + \frac{1}{m}
\end{equation}
meaning that the minimum of $f(a_1,...,a_n)$ is reached when one of the elements is exactly $m$.

Comment: I guess you assume $a_j>0.$ What is $k$ ? If $k$ is not specified the constraint is always satisfied.

Comment: Yes $a_j>0$, I edited thank you. $k$ is a parameter of the problem that scales the sum, I fixed it to $k=2$ so we can simplify the formulation since I'm only interested in the proof of the bound.

Comment: I was thinking $2n^2/2m$ when all $a_i=2m/n$, but then the maximum element is under $m$ in that case.

Comment: Might be helpful: The sum of any two elements greater than $m$ is greater than $2m$, so there can be at most $1$ element greater than $m$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there -- your Monte Carlo simulations do in fact indicate the optimal solution. Here's a full proof:

If $n=1$, the conditions can't be satisfied. If $n=2$, the conditions are always satisfied, and so the optimum is $2/m$ when $a_1=a_2=m$. Otherwise, $a_1\leq m$ since
$$a_1\leq \frac{a_1+\cdots+a_n}n=\frac{2m}n\leq m,$$
and so the only nontrivial condition is $a_n\geq m$.

Applying Cauchy-Schwarz gives
$$\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\frac1{a_i}\right)\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}a_i\right)\geq (n-1)^2,$$
and so
$$\sum_{i=1}^n\frac1{a_i}\geq \frac{(n-1)^2}{2m-a_n}+\frac1{a_n}.$$
Equality is reached if and only if $a_1=\cdots=a_{n-1}=\frac{2m-a_n}{n-1}$. So, the minimum is reached by
$$\min_{m\leq x\leq 2m}\left(\frac{(n-1)^2}{2m-x}+\frac1x\right).$$
Let this function be $f(x)$. We may compute that, for $m\leq x\leq 2m$,
$$f'(x)=\frac{(n-1)^2}{(2m-x)^2}-\frac1{x^2}\geq \frac{(n-1)^2}{m^2}-\frac1{m^2}=\frac{n(n-2)}{m^2}>0,$$
and so $f(x)$ is minimized when $x=m$.

Comment: That's great! Thank you! I'm trying to generalize this proof when the sum is $km$ instead of $2n$. The problem with that is that if $k>n$ the non trivial condition is now $a_1 \leq m$. This leads to finding the lower limit of $f'(x)$ with $0<x \leq m $ (note $x=a_1$ now), which leads to a different result. However Monte Carlo simulations show that in this case ($k>n$) the minimum of $f(a_1,...,a_n)$ is reached when $a_1=m$. What am I missing?

Comment: I am a little concerned about the concept of triviality which has no formal definition if I'm not wrong. I can see that, since $a_1 \leq (2m)/n$ holds, the condition $a_1 \leq m$ becomes redundant, but I cannot grasp how $a_1 \leq (2m)/n$ is automatically embedded as a constraint in the problem

Answer (score 1):

Wow, the solution just blew my mind! You are absolutely correct about monte-carlo. First consider the Am-Gm-Hm inequality, we have

$$\frac{n}{\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{1}{a_i}}\le \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_i}{n} \Rightarrow \sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{1}{a_i} \ge \frac{n^2}{\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_i} = \frac{n^2}{2m}$$

With equality iff $\forall i,j: a_i=a_j=\frac{2m}{n}$ and you get the same result if you write Lagrangian and KKT conditions. But this is correct if the problem is unconstrained, while we have $a_1\le m\le a_n$, therefore we must treat $m$ like an optimization variable. The inequality constraints $a_1\le m \le a_n$ can be written as $-m\le -a_1,\cdots, m\le a_n$ which can be written as $I_i(m-a_1)\le 0$ where $I_i=\pm1$ is some indicator function that governs the sign of inequalities. Therefore in our case the Lagrangian is

$$\mathcal{L} (a_1,\cdots,a_n,m,\nu,\lambda_1\cdots,\lambda_n) = \sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{1}{a_i} + \nu \left( \sum_{i=1}^{n}a_i -2m  \right) + \sum_{i=1}^{n} I_i\lambda_i(m-a_i)$$

and the KKT conditions become

$$\begin{align}
&\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial a_i} =0 \Rightarrow \frac{-1}{a_i^2}+\nu-I_i\lambda_i=0 \\
& \frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial m} = -2\nu + \sum_{i=1}^{n} I_i\lambda_i = 0\\
&\forall i: \lambda_i(m-a_i)=0 \\
&\nu \left( \sum_{i=1}^{n}a_i -2m  \right)=0
\end{align}$$

We know that $\nu \neq 0$ since $\nu \left( \sum_{i=1}^{n}a_i -2m  \right)=0$ and $\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_i = 2m $, this means at least one of $\lambda_i$ is non-zero through equation $\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial m} = -2\nu + \sum_{i=1}^{n} I_i\lambda_i = 0$. Assume $\lambda_j\neq 0$ which in combination with $\lambda_i(m-a_j)=0 $ results in $a_j=m$. This means $\sum_{i=1,i\neq j}^{n}a_i=m$ and since $\forall i: a_i \ge 0$, this means $m\ge 0$ and no other $a_i$ is equal to $m$, or there is exactly two $a_i$'s which are equal to $m$. In the latter case, let's call them $a_j=m,a_k=m$.

The first case results in $a_j=m$ and the unconstrained problem (which we solved at the beginning using AM-HM inequality) $\sum_{i=1,i\neq j}^{n}\frac{1}{a_i}$ subject to $\sum_{i=1,i\neq j}^{n}a_i=m$ and $a_j=m$ which has minimum $\frac{(n-1)^2}{m}+\frac{1}{m}$, or the second case where $a_j=a_k=m$ and rest of $a_i=0$ which has minimum $\frac{2}{m}$ but since $\forall i: a_i > 0$ only the first case is acceptable.

I forgot to mention, the problem is obviously convex, so KKT conditions are necessary and sufficient to find global optimum.

It is obvious because all the constraints are linear and the objective is sum of functions of the form $f(x_i)=\frac{1}{x_i}$. Consider each $f(x_i)$ individually, the hessian is $f''(x_i) = \frac{1}{x_i^3}$ which in the  non-negative orthant, is convex. Now the main objective is positive sum of individual convex functions $\sum_{i=1}^{N}f(x_i)$ which is convex itself since positive summation (and more general case, expectation) conserves convexity. Unfortunately there is no easier way, you should always check convexity through Hessian, definition or [composition rules](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2880725/are-the-standard-rules-for-determining-convexity-of-composition-of-2-functions-a).

Comment: Is the convexity obvious because of the characteristics of the Hessian matrix of $f(a_1,..,a_n)$, or there is quicker way?

Comment: @newman_ash I updated the answer to address the convexity.

Comment: Thanks. Did you mean $f''(x_i) = 1/x_i^3$?

Comment: It might be easier to notice that the Hessian matrix of $f(a_1,...,a_n)$ is a diagonal matrix with positive entries (since $a_i>0$) and thus positive definite

Comment: Yes, those are valid arguments, sometimes it's easier to break it into little parts that can be proved easier but here both methods work well and yes $f''(x_i) = \frac{1}{x_i^3}$ I corrected my version, sorry was working on another problem got me distracted.

Comment: I cannot understand the use of the indicator function. I'd expected that you included the constraints $a_1 - m \leq 0$ and $- a_n +m \leq 0$ as inequality functions in the optimization problem

Comment: That's exactly what I have done, I used indicator function so that I can write all of them with the same notation. For example in the case of $a_1-m\le 0$ we can write it as $m-a_1\ge 0 \Rightarrow (-1)(m-a_1)\le 0 \Rightarrow I_1(m-a_1)\le 0$ where $I_1=-1$. For the $a_n$ on the other hand we have $m-a_n \le 0 \Rightarrow (1)(m-a_n)\le 0 \Rightarrow I_n(m-a_n)\le 0$ where $I_n = 1$. It's just a notational trick to unify all the notations.

Comment: I see, now it's clear thanks a lot. There are still few things that are not clear to me: how can you justify the use of $m$ as part of the optimization set? The value of $m$ is given by the problem and eventually the optimal solution should work for a given $m$. The other thing is $\nu \neq 0$. It could be still $0$ even if $\sum a_i = 2m$.

Answer (score 0):

There can only be one value $\ge m$ else the sum would exceed $2m$. For similar reasons $a_n<2m$. So ignore $a_n$ and apply Lagrange Multipliers to the remaining terms.

All $a_i=(2m-a_n)/(n-1)$.

Plugging $a_n$ back in and using $m\le a_n<2m\implies \frac{1}{2m}<\frac{1}{a_n}<\frac{1}{m}$

$S_2=\sum{\frac{1}{a_i}}>\frac{(n-1)^2}{(2m-a_n)}+\frac{1}{a_n}>\frac{(n-1)^2}{(2m-a_n)}+\frac{1}{2m}$

Comment: Hi, unfortunately plugging these inequalities for $a_n$ in the last term would result in a looser bound with respect to the minimum I found